# What does it mean when it says (variable type) before an operation?

Tags: c++, types

I see this often, but not always, that when an already declared variable has its type in parentheses before performing some basic operation.
For example:

`avg = ((float)sum)/size; //even though all of these variables have already been declared)`

or

`vector.push_back( (float)*t - x);`

When does one do this, and why? What does it mean?

Comment: This is called a cast.

Comment: You might guess that this could be an operator. With that, you can get your answer by looking at a [precedence table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), eventually making your way to a [page with more information](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast).

Comment: Further this is often referred to as "C style cast" (e,g, in the reference for [explicit type conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)) - C++ introduced more casting options in the form of `static_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `const_cast` and `dynamic_cast`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known as [typecasting](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson11.html), which basically makes the variable act as that type for the current operation. It's useful in a bunch of different scenarios. For your first example, the reason for the float is presumably so that the division of the two numbers doesn't default to integer division since you want an average. `(int) 1/ (int) 3 == 0`, but `(float) 1/ (int) 3 == 0.33...`